# What type of code is this?

Tags: php, json

I'm in grade 7 and I am building a site for our class. I am trying to use some forum and in my xampp database, this is under "recipents". What type of code is this?

```
a:1:{s:2:"to";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a serialized array. `a:1:{s:2:"to";a:2:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";}}` is the output of

```
echo serialize([
    'to' => ['1', '2']
]);
```